# Undefined media issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I maintaine the web site of a friend of mine, and the console logs the following error:

```
GET https://www.my-client-site.ext/undefined 404 (Not Found)       undefined:1
```

The problem is that I can't find the location of this call in the page.

I have try to search the page source code, and I cannot find any referense to this URL.

Also I have try to check JS files with break points, and still I cannot find this issue.

Is there any other way to make reseach for this particular issue ?

Comment: Hello @solai, I am using chrome, but I can use FF too if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to firefox and install addon called Firebug.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Now Open firebug and go to console tab, 
Firebug will show your javascript which is calling ajax in right corner of the pane.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this, doesn't help. I can track the Ajax requests with the Chrome console too. The question is, how to locate the request position into my script.